# JavaScript: How to handle an UCS-2 File?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I have an Javascript (AngularJS) App, and I try to load an language-file, which is converted in "UCS-2 Little Endian".

I have to use this, and are not allowed to convert the file to UTF-8.

Now the problem is, that I can´t read this file in JavaScript.

```
// console.log(row);
��[�l�a�n�g�_�d�e�_�n�a�m�e�]�,�G�e�r�m�a�n�
```

Instead this row should be:

```
[lang_de_name],German
```

Is there any way to read the file without changing the file? I already tried encodeURIComponent() or escape(), which does not work.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Link: http://terenceyim.wordpress.com/tag/ucs2/

What I do in code now:

```
var csv = UTF8.decode(UTF8.encode(row))
```

Works.